# .inject() and .goto() methods not work on nightmare

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I have been scraping with `Nightmare` for a few days, my problem is to load a page and include `jQuery` using `.inject()`
I wrote this code;

```
const Nightmare = require ('nightmare');
var nightmare = new Nightmare ();

nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .inject('js', __dirname + /jquery.min.js')
    .evaluate(fn(){
               /*I need to extract some information from the page but when 
               I try to use the DOM object or the jQuery's '$' it shows 
               me an error saying that no document is defined*/
     })
    .wait(500);
```

PHPstorm (an IDE that I use to program in JS and PHP) mark `.goto()` and `.inject()` and drop the warning message `unresolved function or method .goto()` and `unresolved function or method .inject()`

What do I need to do to load the page? Maybe there is not enough time?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
.inject('js', __dirname + /jquery.min.js')'
```

should be

```
.inject('js', __dirname + '/jquery.min.js')'
```

You're missing a quote